# Why does building with Microsoft.Xml.SgmlReader 1.8.18 nuget output this warning MSB2346

Tags: .net-core, sgmlreader

I'm using the [Microsoft.Xml.SgmlReader nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xml.SgmlReader/1.8.18) in several places of my .Net Core 3.1 projects.

The build output says:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2123,5): warning MSB3246: Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. Could not load file or assembly 'SgmlReader.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I'm unable to google what this really means or how I fix it. Maybe I should be using a different incarnation of the SgmlReader nuget, only this one (1.8.18) seems to be the one most up-to-date.

Edit:
No information reg. sgmlreader in fusion logs when building (or starting VS2019).
But I did notice these two in the references:
[Compile Time Assemblies, SgmlReader.exe and SgmlReaderDll.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxCp8.png)
I can open SgmlReaderDll.dll in JustDecompile, but not SgmlReader.exe.
I also notice that the exe is part of netcoreapp3.1, but not netstandard2.0 and netstandard2.1. That does not look right to me.

Comment: capture a [fusion log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29374658/1466046) to maybe see more details

Comment: Please notice that I edited the post - sorry no fusion log data.